# PHP fopen using file mask

Tags: php, file, fopen, mask

Is it possible/how can I open a text file in PHP using a file mask?

The files are going to be named for example:

abcdef_072810_999222.txt
abcdef_072910_123456.txt
abcdef_073010_888884.txt

So I want to fopen or rename the file like this (notice the * mask)  :

"abcdef_".date("mdy")."_*.txt"

I would like to avoid a read directory contents, loop through ... if possible.

Comment: Can you give more details of really what you want to do? Open, rename?.. Why without looping?

Comment: if looping is the only way, fine, I was just hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```